# Need help on populating results from a data spreadsheet onto a summary sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying place the formulas so that when I type in the name on the output spreadsheet, Excel will pull the information from cells in the data sheet, *column B* based on the name in *J5* checked matched against the names in *row 3* and which values are marked **X**.

Initially for single output values I used an `index match match` function but don't think that works as well for this situation...

Any advice would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: It would have been better to post a screenshot. To take a screenshot on Windows, press the Print Screen key and paste it into Paint by pressing CTRL+V.

Answer (score 0):

Use OFFSET()

Somewhere in your workbook (I'd use a separate tab that's dedicated to "behind the curtain" variables), add a formula of MATCH(J5,C3:H3,0) and give that cell a name, like "ClientColumn"

Where before, you were able to test if John Doe had checked "Harmonious" by testing C6, now you can test if the client named in J5 checked "Harmonious" by testing OFFSET(B6,0,ClientColumn)